# show AutoCompleteTextView using txt file data in android

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview

I want to add AutoCompleteTextView in my application. I have one txt file in that there are more than 2000 records are present. I want to use it for AutoCompleteTextView. Normally for small data we use array as:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,dataArray);
       AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
       actv.setThreshold(1);
       actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But now how to use txt file for AutoCompleteTextView. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you separating elements in your text file? Assuming that you have a new elements on each line you can use this to convert the file to an array, the use the array adapter as you have mentioned above.

```
   String[] arr= null;
   List<String> items= new ArrayList<String>();

    try 
    { 
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("text1.txt"); 
        DataInputStream data_input = new DataInputStream(fstream); 
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data_input)); 
        String str_line; 

        while ((str_line = buffer.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
            str_line = str_line.trim(); 
            if ((str_line.length()!=0))  
            { 
                items.add(str_line);
            } 
        }

        arr = (String[])items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 create one string resource file like "string_autocompletearray" and define your array.

**res/values/string_autocompletearray.xml**
 string-array name="autocomplete_array">
    <item>AutoCompleteText 1 </item>
    <item>AutoCompleteText 2 </item>
    -------------------------------
    -------------------------------
    <item>AutoCompleteText N </item>
</string-array>

**Now find this array and set to adapter**
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.autocomplete_array)));
```